# inverse fast fourier transform for frequency range

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

My problem is to obtain original signal from amplitude spectrum (fft) based on inverse fft but only for some frequency range ex. 8-12 Hz. Could anyone help me? I try to used:

```
xdft=fft(x); 
ixdft=ifft(xdft(a:b)), %where xdft(a:b) is |Y(f)| for freq 8-12 Hz.
```

But it doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set all the values of `xdft` to zero except those you want, i.e.,

```
xdft = fft(x);
xdft = xdft(1:ceil(length(xdft) / 2));
xdft(1:a) = 0;
xdft(b+1:end) = 0;
ixdft = ifft(xdft, 'symmetric');
```

The reason I have taken only half of the original FFT'd data is that your result will be symmetric about Fs / 2 (where Fs is the sample rate), and if you don't do the same thing to the frequencies either side of the centre, you will get a complex signal out. Instead of doing the same thing to both sides manually, I've just taken one side, modified it, and told `ifft` that it has to reconstruct the data for the full frequency range by appending a mirror image of what you pass it; this by done by calling it with the `'symmetric'` option.

If you need to figure out what `a` and `b` should be for some frequency, you can first create a vector of the frequencies at which you've performed the FFT, then find those frequencies that are within your range, like so:

```
xdft = fft(x);
xdft = xdft(1:ceil(length(xdft) / 2));
f = linspace(0, Fs / 2, length(xdft));
keepInd = f >= 8 & f <= 12; % Keep frequencies between 8 and 12 Hz
xdft(~keepInd) = 0;
```

Note that I've actually omitted the use of the two variables `a` and `b` altogether in this example and opted for logical indexing, and that `Fs` is the sample rate.